# Magento profiler, manually output selected profiles

Tags: profiler

How do we manually output profiler results? For example if we wanted to output just few keys/sections? Right now when we switch on the profiler it will output all sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, in order to turn on Magento profiler, basically you need to do these two steps.

1) Make `System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug > Profiler` to  `Yes`.

2) Uncomment the line `Varien_Profiler::enable()` which comes inside `index.php`.

So the second step is what you need to alter in your case. Since the line `Varien_Profiler::enable()` is included before the application runner code `Mage::run()`, this means profiler is enabled globally.

So what you want to do is, remove or comment out `Varien_Profiler::enable()` line of code from `index.php` and then  put that line wherever you want to see the output. If you don't want to see the *profiler buckets*<sup>**1**</sup> other than your custom profiler buckets, then after your buckets, you should disable  profiler by putting `Varien_Profiler::disable()`.

So basically, this is what you need to do.

```
//enables profiler
Varien_Profiler::enable();

//your custom profiler buckets starts
Varien_Profiler::start('unique_code')

/**
 * You custom code comes here
 *
 */

//your custom profiler buckets ends.
Varien_Profiler::stop('unique_code');

//disables profiler to avoid further profiling
Varien_Profiler::disable()
```

That's it. Now clear all cache and load the page again. You will see the profiler data only from your custom profiler buckets.

***Note:*** Other than this manual enabling, I am not aware of any other better profiler enabling/disabling technique.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> Profiler buckets are codes that comes in  between a particular  `Varien_Profiler::start('unique_code')` and  `Varien_Profiler::stop('unique_code')`.